# Programmatically created integration is not working properly

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.4.5, integration

I read the documentation of [creating integration](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/create-integration/).
I get my integration and I have the below permissions in my ***etc/integration/api.xml***

```
<integrations>
<integration name="TestMagentoIntegration">
    <resources>

        <resource name="Magento_Backend::dashboard" />
        <resource name="Magento_Analytics::analytics" />
        <resource name="Magento_Analytics::analytics_api" />

        <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_operation" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_order" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::create" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions_edit" />

        <resource name="Magento_Backend::stores" />
        <resource name="Magento_Backend::stores_settings" />
        <resource name="Magento_Config::config" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::config_catalog" />
        <resource name="Magento_CatalogSearch::config_catalog_search" />
        <resource name="Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::order_statuses" />

        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::inventory" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::source" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::source_edit" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::ship_source_selection" />

        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::stock" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::stock_edit" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::stock_delete" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventorySalesApi::stock" />
        <resource name="Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency" />

        <resource name="Magento_Backend::stores_attributes" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::sets" />
        <resource name="Magento_Backend::system" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::adobe_stock_asset" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_delete" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_save" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_view" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_get" />
    </resources>
</integration>
```

I can generate ***oauth_token and oauth_token_secret*** successfully. But when I want to get order data using API it shows me an error.
API:

```
http://dev.magento.com/rest/V1/orders/5
```

Response:

```
"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
"parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Sales::actions_view"
},
```

If I create manually it works fine. But I need it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

- Settings => All Users

and make sure your api user is in a role that has access to the orders.

Comment: There is no user without admin. How I can make a user for my integration?

Comment: You have the option to add a new user on the top right corner. I'd create a role named APIRole and give that role the necessary permissions. Then I'd create the api user and associate it with the role

Comment: But I have to create it programmatically.